# What are the heaviest parts of modern DSLR bodies?

Tags: dslr, body, canon-60d, canon-600d

60D = 755g
600D = 560g

Both are built on an aluminium chassis. The only difference I can think of is a pentaprism. Is it really that heavy? Almost + 200g

What are the other heavy parts?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the 600D is a plastic chassis, not aluminium. What's your source for saying it's aluminium?

Comment: [Dpreview](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canoneos600d/2) says the body material is "Stainless steel and polycarbonate resin with glass fiber."

Comment: Should the title really be changed to "why is camera x heavier than camera y?"? I like the idea of a generalized question, but thus far the answers and really the question are specific to these models.

Comment: @EsaPaulasto Canon's own specs list the 600D as "polycarbonate". Canon lists the 60D as "polycarbonate resin with glass fiber on an aluminum chassis."

Comment: @MichaelClark - Canon's own specs on 600D say **"Body Materials: Stainless Steel and polycarbonate resin with conductive fiber"** near the end of the specs page at [www.canon-europe.com](http://www.canon-europe.com/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/Digital_SLR/EOS_600D/#p-specification) but it could be that _stainless steel_ is a material not worthy of mentioning on some other Canon sites. Besides, I don't believe any maker would create a DSLR body made of polycarbonate alone.

Comment: The Canon U.S. site no longer says anything. Various review sites are split on it. To the best of my knowledge all of the Canon polycarbonate bodies include the fiberglass fiber in the mix before it is molded. ALL Canon EOS bodies have an engineering grade plastic light box that is supposed to be stronger than steel. So do all of the recent Nikon bodies. I've not been able to find a "cut-out" graphic of the 600D similar to ones of other Rebel series, but if the 600D is similar the stainless steel parts are more of an internal structure the various PC boards are mounted to than anything else.

Comment: At any rate, in the context of this discussion, the three largest factors are the difference in battery weight, size difference between the two bodies, and the solid pentaprism (made of fairly dense material) vs. the hollow penta-mirror.

Comment: Imagine a pentaprism as a walnut size piece of solid, probably leaded(!), glass... 200g is not infeasible here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Canon lists the body-only mass of the 60D at 675 grams and the 600D at 515 grams. These numbers are without batteries. Include the batteries and the 60D is the 755g you quote in your question, but the 600D is only 540g.

- The 60D chassis is polycarbonate resin (plastic) with glass fiber on an aluminum chassis and moderately weather sealed. The 600D chassis is polycarbonate resin with glass fiber. It uses some internal stainless steel, but it is not really a metal chassis.
- The 60D uses the LP-E6 battery (2.9 oz./82g), the 600D uses the LP-E8 (0.8 oz./23g), so 60 grams of the total difference is the battery weight. That is a little more than 1/4.
- The volume of the L x W x H measurements of the 60D is about 13% larger than the 600 D. When sitting them side by side, though, the boxy, rectangular 60D appears more than 1/8 larger than the angular 600D. Assuming uniform density, 13% of the 560g mass of the 600D is 72 grams., that is roughly another 1/3 of the difference.
- The 600D viewfinder uses a pentamirror which is basically a hollow construct with five mirrors for walls. The bottom and rear are 'two-way' mirrors to allow light in from the bottom and out through the back. The 60D uses a pentaprism, which is a similarly shaped but solid piece of fairly dense material.